# Is this published upper bound on the n'th prime wrong?

Tags: prime-numbers

This [paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/jaroma03200545640.pdf) gives an upper bound on the n'th prime for $n\ge7022$ 
 as:$$p_n\le n(\log{n} + \log{\log{n}}-0.9385)$$ citing the reference 
*Robin, Guy*, [**Estimate of the Chebyshev theta function on the $k$th prime number and large values of the number of prime divisors function $\omega(n)$ of $n$**](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa42/aa4242.pdf), Acta Arith. 42, 367-389 (1983). [ZBL0475.10034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0475.10034).
This paper in turn attributes the expression to Rosser in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/plms/article-abstract/s2-45/1/21/1441502) (one that I have not been able to access).

But $p[8597]=88789$ whereas the upper bound given by the above expression is $\approx88759$.  I am wondering if the original paper contains an error or whether the original expression has been wrongly quoted. Could anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: The article is available here: https://sci-hub.mn/https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-45.1.21#

Comment: Thank you - I am most grateful for your helpful comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upper bounds for $p_n$, and estimates of $\pi(x)$ are often incorrect, see also the remarks in [this article](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_23_cheby_error.pdf). I can confirm your computation. 
I think, Dusart's estimates are more reliable, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442.pdf). It seems to me that Rosser's paper is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your input and for your informative article.